# How to stop active effect occurring on all sub menu options from navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I currently have [this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/404pwuqq/2/) in which I was working on yesterday. I have successfully added a submenu (within 'Allocations') to include the effect when clicked on.

However, when I click on `#1`, `#2`also has the effect.

As i am still a long way of being competant with css, I would greatly appreciate any help possible to removing the 'active' effect to only the parent and 'clicked' child, without having the siblings also have the effect (I think it's due to parent having effect, but I'm not 100% sure).

```js
  $('li').click(function() {

    $(this).addClass('active')
      .siblings()
      .removeClass('active');

  });
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #444;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #eee;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.nav-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 2px black;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  /*height:50px; */
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(#292929, #242424);
}
a {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  /*height:100%;*/
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #bbb;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 25%;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.active a {
  color: #B93632;
  border-left: 5px solid #B93632;
  background-color: #1B1B1B;
  outline: 0;
}
li:not(.active):hover a {
  color: #eee;
  border-left: 5px solid #FCFCFC;
  background-color: #1B1B1B;
}
span[class ^="icon"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  /*CHANGED*/
  font-size: 1.5em;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 250px) {
  .text {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-container,
  a {
    width: 70px;
  }
  #ContentSplitter_0 {
    width: 32px;
  }
  a:hover {
    width: 200%;
    z-index: 1;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px black;
  }
  a:hover .text {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 30%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 200px) {
  .nav-container,
  a {
    width: 33%;
  }
  span[class ^="icon"] {
    left: 2%;
  }
}
/*********************************************extra*******************************************/

.nav li ul {
  display: none;
  /* Hides the drop-down menu */
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  /* Aligns drop-down box underneath the menu item */
  padding: 0;
  /* Aligns drop-down box underneath the menu item */
}
.nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  /* Displays the drop-down box when the menu item is hovered over */
  z-index: 12;
  padding-left: 1px;
}
.nav li ul li a {
  border-left: 1px solid #0026ff;
  border-right: 1px solid #0026ff;
  border-top: 1px solid #0026ff;
  z-index: 99;
}
.nav li ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #0094ff;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.option {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.navImg {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-left: -2%;
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.subChild {
  visibility: visible;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 10000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon" style="margin-left:5px">
                            <img src="~/Content/Images/Home.png" width="32" height="32" style="margin-left:-2%; padding-top:4px" />
                        </span>
        <span class="text option">home</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon"> <img src="~/Content/Images/Reports.png" width="32" height="32" style="margin-left:-2%; padding-top:4px" /></span>
        <span class="text option">Reports</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon"><img src="~/Content/Images/Allocations.png" width="32" height="32" style="margin-left:-2%; padding-top:4px" /></span>
        <span class="text option">Allocations</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="subChild">
        <li><a href="#"> #1 </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> #2 </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <span class="text option">Database</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <span class="text option">Orders</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon"><img src="~/Content/Images/Settings.png" width="32" height="32" style="margin-left:-2%; padding-top:4px" /></span>
        <span class="text option">Admin/Settings</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon"><img src="~/Content/Images/User.png" width="32" height="32" style="margin-left:-2%; padding-top:4px" /></span>
        <span class="text option">Users</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How is it possible to remove the effect from the siblings when I click on `#1`?

Please Note, the same issue occurs when the parent is clicked (since it will take you to an 'overview', I wish for the children NOT to have the active effect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to mess with it a bit to get the desired effect, but I'm sure in the end you don't care about a few adjustments

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/404pwuqq/6/
edit: fixed fiddle

New jQuery:

```
 $('ul li').click(function () {
     $('li').removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');
     var parent = $(this).parent().prev();
     if (parent.attr('id') == 'aloc') {
        parent.addClass('active');
     }
 });
```

Left the `.active a` as is.

CSS changed:

```
// This was the css for the dropdown to show.
// for some reason the selector line below is commented out, it shouldnt be.

// Was .nav li:hover ul 
#aloc:hover ~ .subChild, .subChild:hover {
  display: block;
  /* Displays the drop-down box when the menu item is hovered over */
  z-index: 12;
  padding-left: 1px;
}

// This was the CSS for the .subChild, I combined the .nav li ul
// and .subChild into the one below 

.subChild {
  display: none;
  /* Hides the drop-down menu */
  margin: 0;
  /* Aligns drop-down box underneath the menu item */
  padding: 0;
  z-index:10000;
  /* Aligns drop-down box underneath the menu item */
 }
```

I adjusted your html to place the `.subChild` ul outside of the Allocations li so the list items don't get affected (This was the main problem). The use of the above CSS achieves the same effect of the dropdown.

The HTML for the Allocations LI and submenu now look like the below snipped. Also included an id for the allocations LI for the logic in the jQuery above:

```
<li id='aloc'> 
  <a href="#">
  <span class="icon"><img src="~/Content/Images/Allocations.png" width="32" height="32" style="margin-left:-2%; padding-top:4px" /></span>
   <span class="text option">Allocations</span>
 </a>
 </li>
 <ul class="subChild">
            <li><a href="#"> #1 </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"> #2 </a>
            </li>
 </ul>
```

If theres anything else that changed, I provided the working fiddle above. Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks - it's almost perfect :P. I really appreciate your help; but try doing: click '#2' -> click 'Reports' -> click 'allocations'. Would there be a way of ensuring '#2' doesn't highlight when 'allocations' is "reclicked" if you see what I mean? Other than that it's exactly what I need!

Comment: Haha try again sorry, Im kinda new to fiddle. I didn't 'update' it from the fiddle you provided. I edited it and included the new link

Comment: there's a tiny bit of invalid markup with the **ul** being placed out of the **li** block, but it works so that's the important part

Comment: Hmm are you stuck on the list items? Cause as it stands, jQuery's $(this) returns the entire list item when clicking on allocations, so its hard not to target the items nested within it.

Comment: Change the 'li' in your jquery to 'a' and adjust your '.active a' to just '.active' and adjust the 'li :not(active):hover a' to 'li:hover a' and adust certain styles accordingly. Best best is to target the 'a' elements and not thr 'li' elements. Ill update my answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

With a small change in your css:

```
.active > a {
    color: #B93632;
    border-left:5px solid #B93632;
    background-color: #1B1B1B;
    outline:0;
}
```

Here, it selects only the immediate child.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/404pwuqq/4/)**

Comment: Thanks - it's *almost* perfect :P. I really appreciate your help; but try doing: click '#2' -> click 'Reports' -> click 'allocations'. Would there be a way of ensuring '#2' doesn't highlight  when 'allocations' is "reclicked" if you see what I mean? Other than that it's exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Editing this:

`.active > a, .nav li ul li a:focus {
    color: #B93632;
    border-left:5px solid #B93632;
    background-color: #1B1B1B;
    outline:0;
}`

the problem " '#2' doesn't highlight when 'allocations' is "reclicked"" is solved.